# How to specify specific index for generic, user-defined type in Ada?

Tags: generics, ada

So I have a generic package with a user-defined formal parameter:

```
type element is (<>);
```

The type is discrete because I am in part using it as an index throughout my program. So let's say I have two different arrays, one in which I can just put "element" like so:

```
array1 : array (element) of integer;
```

and a second array in which the beginning index is one less than that of array1, hypothetically, written like this:

```
array2 : array (1_less_than_element .. element) of integer;
```

How would I specify that I wish for array2 to start at one less index value than array1?

Also, it's worth mentioning that my program is about topological sorting, and at the beginning I am to get the total number of relations (NR) to sort through. Previously, when I believed the program did not have to be generic and everything was going to involve integers, I simply put:

```
array1 : array (1 .. NR) of integer;
array2 : array (0 .. NR) of integer;
```

However, now that's it's generic, I'm not sure how to specify the equivalent, as the specifications seem to indicate that the index must be of type element.

Comment: Do the package's users need to see these two arrays? or are they just part of the implementation?

Comment: The users won't have direct access to the arrays. They mostly just provide actual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the solution. For the sake of posterity, I will go ahead and post the answer here. If I am mistaken or there is a better way, etc, please post and/or let me know.

Since a discrete type is a descendant of the scalar type in Ada, it inherits the attributes of the scalar type. One such attribute is Scalar'Pred(Arg : X), which returns the value preceding X in an enumeration type. For numeric types, it basically just decrements the index.

Comment: This will work for signed integer type definitions (`type Element is range <>`, [ARM12.5.2(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-5-2.html#p3)) but not in general for discrete type definitions, because `Element’Pred (Element’First)` will give you a compilation error if `Element` is an enumeration. Look at `Ada.Containers.Vectors` ([ARM A.18.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html), and particularly [(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html#p7)).

Comment: I don't have access to the documentation I found atm, but I believe I read that this would work for enumeration types.

Comment: Which I think would make since enumeration indirectly inherits from scalar. Why would it give me a compilation error for enumeration types?

Comment: Consider `type Boolean is (False, True);`. There _is_ no `Boolean` value before `First`. (I don’t know if you’ve come across thedailywtf.com; the guys there might try to persuade you that it’d be `FILE_NOT_FOUND` :-) Anyway, try it; the compiler says `instantiation error`/`Pred of “Boolean’First"`/`static expression fails Constraint_Check`.

Comment: I see what you mean. So would it be better to go with array1 : array (element'succ (element'first) .. element'last) of element? That way it achieves the indices relative to one another in the way that I want without going into the "non-existent zone." I'm at work on my phone so I can't test it out right now.

Comment: That would work. But do you really need to allow enumerations? Would it make sense for the user to specify an enumeration and then for you not to use the first value? This is the reason for the `Ada.Containers.Vectors` design.